# Publish layout thumbnail file names changed after update

Tags: publish-layout, image-path, thumbnails, filename

I recently updated a site from 2.1.x to v2.7.3

I've synced my file directories, images display on the front-end just fine. But I'm having issues with the thumbnails in publish layouts (they show in the file browser and file manager fine as well).

So for example, this is what I see in the admin:

[image: Screenshot]

The path to the missing image is /images/uploads/instruments/_thumbs/TEN_ANN_FA.png

On my server, the file is definitely there, but it has "thumb_" appended to it: /images/uploads/instruments/_thumbs/thumb_TEN_ANN_FA.png

This is the same case for ALL of the thumbnails in the publish layouts.

Any ideas why this has happened?  And is there somewhere in the config I can manipulate the thumbnail file names so that it finds them correctly?

Comment: Don't know why this occurred, but you could add the `thumb_` prefix in the database manually!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try if you haven't already.

1. rename _thumbs to _thumbs_OLD
2. In the control panel, navigate to **Content > Files > File Upload Preferences**
3. Click on the Synchronize button for the upload destination having issues.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! That worked! Thank you so much @Anna_MediaGirl :)